# Problems with native query spring data JPA returns empty JSON array with empty objects

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, nativequery

I'm learning spring 5 MVC with spring data JPA and sql queries

I'm trying to use a native query in my spring api restful example but when I run the project, my method returns an empty json object.

My Model class

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "bicycle")
public class Bicycle
{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;
    
    @Column(name="name")
    private String name;
    
    @Column(name="year")
    private int year;
}
```

My repository class

```
@Repository
public interface BicycleRepository extends CrudRepository<Bicycle, Long>
{
    @Query(value = "SELECT * from db_bicycles.bicycle", nativeQuery = true)
    public List<Bicycle> obtenerTodos();
}
```

My controller class

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class BicycleController
{
    @Autowired
    private BicycleRepository bicycleRepository;
    
    //create get all bicycles
    @GetMapping("/bicycles")
    public List<Bicycle> getAllBicycles()
    {
        return bicycleRepository.obtenerTodos();
    }   
}
```

My application properties

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost/db_bicycles?useUnicode=true&useJDBCCompilantTimeZoneShift=true&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&serverTimezone=UTC
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=root
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
```

This table have 2 rows.

[image]

Comment: Hi, What did you mean by db_bicycles. Thanks

Comment: In your Bicycle class , is there any getter and setter ? If not try adding getter and setter and try again.

Comment: Yes, for some reason STS only make me setters and no getters, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

1. use getter/setter in your POJO class
2. you need not to write query to retrieve all record. Simply you can make use of findAll() method
   which is available in crudeRepository.

`bicycleRepository.findAll();`   (will return list of your POJO class.)

3. make sure, there is data present in table. if not then make use of Setter/Construction

Injection to populate data. OR you can make a POST call to populate data in table using save() method.

Comment: I cant use hibernate like orm (mapping foreign key, etc). The tables often changes and a native query helps to avoid crashes, simply replace the sql query and the result is the same like the class I create.

Comment: Not agree, what you had shared here a/c that I explained.  If table often changes then we will have lots of approach. Anyways it's up to you how you gonna deal with your code

Comment: company politics, the company say must be sql with JPA and no spring JDBCTemplate

Answer (score 1):

If you are using lombok and Spring Tools Suite in your project, then try running Maven Clean and Maven Install.

```
mvn clean install
```

After that, you can run the project. It should work.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to add the getter and setters, eclipse (STS) only add me the setters